# Azure Service Bus in .Net Core - how to receive only one message

Tags: azure, .net-core, queue, azureservicebus

I'd like to use Azure Service Bus on .Net Core and read only one message. It seems that `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` does not support such a case. So far testing code a bit got me this far:

```
public void ReceiveOne()
{
    var queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, "go_testing");

    queueClient.RegisterMessageHandler(
        async (message, token) =>
        {
            var messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);
            Console.WriteLine($"Received: {messageBody}, time: {DateTime.Now}");
            await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);

            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        },
        new MessageHandlerOptions(async args => Console.WriteLine(args.Exception))
        { MaxConcurrentCalls = 1, AutoComplete = false });
}
```

So I'm closing queue after successfully reading one message. It works, but it also triggers an exception.

Do you know a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 10):

I found a solution:

```
IMessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

// Receive the message
Message message = await messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync();

// Process the message
Console.WriteLine($"Received message: SequenceNumber:{message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber} Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}");

// Complete the message so that it is not received again.
// This can be done only if the MessageReceiver is created in ReceiveMode.PeekLock mode (which is default).
await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
await messageReceiver.CloseAsync();
```

You will need to include:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core;
```

This is the original source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/GettingStarted/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/SendReceiveUsingMessageSenderReceiver

Comment: what if i want to read all the available messages from topic?

Comment: If you want to read all messages you can just use the code from the MS docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions#receive-messages-from-the-subscription

Answer (score 0):

RegisterMessageHandler is a convenience API for receiving all the messages that appear on your queue.

You want the lower-level API [queueClient.ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.receiveasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueClient_ReceiveAsync_System_TimeSpan_)

> **ReceiveAsync()**
>
> Asynchronously receives a message

See this sample [Receive Loop](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/ReceiveLoop) for how to receive multiple messages (if you want) using the ReceiveAsync API.

Comment: So I have to use this older package - WindowsAzure.ServiceBus. But it seems that it does not work on .Net Core or .Net Standard?

Comment: The .net standard library has the same methods.

Comment: It seems that this library is totally unsuitable for reading one message at a time because the acknowledgement methods are all async and buffering, and there is no way to lower the buffering timeout, unlike in the WindowsAzure library. Therefore the call to CompleteAsync will have a high latency and your throughput will be very poor. Not sure why this functionality is missing if it was in the other library, but it's a pain.